# Contentful .NET SDK Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException Deserializing JSON to POCO

Tags: json, .net-core, contentful, headless-cms

**Update 1 8.July.2020**: Maybe I should not have started with the Rich Text field type, which seems to take quite a bit of additional work to access:

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/net/tutorials/rich-text/

**Update 2 9.July.2020**: No wonder it cannot serialize Rich Text to a string. Look how it stores the Rich Text:

"fields": {
"richTextField": {
"nodeType": "document",
"data": {},
"content": [
{
"nodeType": "paragraph",
"content": [
{
"nodeType": "text",
"value": "This is the ",
"marks": [],
"data": {}
},
{
"nodeType": "text",
"value": "rich text",
"marks": [
{
"type": "underline"
}
],
"data": {}
},
{
"nodeType": "text",
"value": " field.",
"marks": [],
"data": {}
}
],
"data": {}
}
]
},

This doesn't look fun to reassemble into HTML. If I wanted it broken down, I would use HtmlAgilityPack.

**Update 3 9.July.2020:**

Actually, this doesn't make any sense. This documentation suggests that my models use this Contentful Document class in my POCOs and that they should contain additional Contentful-specific code for accessing data.

One of the main goals of headless CMS is to avoid vendor-specific APIs (lock-in). The way that works is that the CMS just hydrates POCOs, basically deserializing from JSON. No other headless CMS is going to populate a structure like this from Rich Text, so just using this crazy format for HTML leads to vendor-lock-in or the need for a major code overhaul just to change the CMS (not just changing the POCO hydration logic, but changing the POCOs themselves). Not to mention the JSON payload and CPU load impact of structuring HTML like this. In any case, with the Contentful architecture just for Rich Text Fields (probably one of the most common elements in a CMS), there is a bunch of vendor-specific coding just to get the value and the front-end becomes way too aware of the CMS. So I would have to deserialize to some kind of intermediary objects and then use those to populate my view models. Or I could replicate all of the logic around Document into my own project, but that sounds almost worse.

I don't see how anyone can use this system. Please correct my misperceptions.

**Original thread**

I posted this on https://www.contentfulcommunity.com/, but I don't know how to get that post through the moderators.

I try to follow these instructions for the Contentful .NET SDK to access an Entry:

https://github.com/contentful/contentful.net

I may be using newer .NET Core, but it doesn’t compile that way. This compiles:

```
using Contentful.Core;
using Contentful.Core.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace CfClt
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Entry
        {
            public string richTextField { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            ContentfulOptions options = new ContentfulOptions
            {
                DeliveryApiKey = "A",
                PreviewApiKey = "B",
                SpaceId = "C"
            };

            ContentfulClient client = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, options);
            Entry entry = client.GetEntry<Entry>("4SVaB1ps4H6Ml9ZxWsCWOn").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(entry.richTextField);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an exception deserializing from JSON to the POCO. Here is the JSON for the Entry:

```
{
  "sys": {
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "qjiunow8a0ig"
      }
    },
    "id": "4SVaB1ps4H6Ml9ZxWsCWOn",
    "type": "Entry",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-08T19:52:47.34Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-08T19:52:47.34Z",
    "environment": {
      "sys": {
        "id": "master",
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Environment"
      }
    },
    "revision": 1,
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "firstContentType"
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
  "fields": {
    "richTextField": {
      "nodeType": "document",
      "data": {},
      "content": [
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "this is the rich text field. What is my ID?",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'fields.richTextField', line 32, position 22.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T](JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Contentful.Core.ContentfulClient.GetEntry[T](String entryId, String queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\temp\cfclt\CfClt\Contentful.Core\ContentfulClient.cs:line 136
   at CfClt.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\temp\cfclt\CfClt\CfClt\Program.cs:line 26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using Contentful.Core;
    using Contentful.Core.Configuration;
    using Contentful.Core.Models;
    using Deliverystack.Core.Fulcontent.Models.Repositories;
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    
    namespace cfclt
    {
        class Program
        {
            public class Entry
            {
                public string StringField { get; set; }
                public string Url { get; set;  }
                public Document RichTextField { get; set; }
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                ContentfulOptions options = new ContentfulOptions
                {
                    DeliveryApiKey = "A",
                    PreviewApiKey = "B",
                    SpaceId = "C"
                };
    
                ContentfulClient client = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, options);
                ContentfulRepository repository = new ContentfulRepository(client);
                Entry entry = repository.Get<Entry>("/");
                Console.WriteLine(entry + " : " + entry.StringField + " : " + entry.Url + " : " + new HtmlRenderer().ToHtml(entry.RichTextField).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            }
        }
    }
    
using Contentful.Core;
using Contentful.Core.Models;
using Contentful.Core.Search;
using Deliverystack.Core.Models.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Deliverystack.Core.Fulcontent.Models.Repositories
{
    public class ContentfulRepository : IRepository
    {
        private ContentfulClient _client;

        public ContentfulRepository(ContentfulClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public override TEntryModel Get<TEntryModel>(string entryIdentifier, string contentTypeUid = null)
        {
            TEntryModel result = null;

            if (!entryIdentifier.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                result = _client.GetEntry<TEntryModel>(entryIdentifier).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> contentTypes = new List<string>();

                if (contentTypeUid != null)
                {
                    contentTypes.Add(contentTypeUid);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (ContentType doNotUseCt in _client.GetContentTypes().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                    {
                        ContentType myContentType = doNotUseCt;
                        contentTypes.Add(myContentType.SystemProperties.Id);
                    }
                }

                foreach(string doNotUseCti in contentTypes)
                { 
                    string myContentTypeUid = doNotUseCti;
                    QueryBuilder<TEntryModel> queryBuilder = QueryBuilder<TEntryModel>.New.ContentTypeIs(myContentTypeUid).FieldEquals("fields.url", entryIdentifier);
                    ContentfulCollection<TEntryModel> entries = _client.GetEntries(queryBuilder).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    if (entries.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        result = entries.Items.First();
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Actually this is a bit non-deterministic because multiple entries in multiple content types could have a common URL, in which case this would return one of them, but would those other threads possibly override result afterwords, changing the data returned to the caller after this method has already returned that data? Maybe I need to create threads explicitly and cancel those threads on the first match.